# Amount of statements in java - Definition of a statement

Tags: java

I don't quite understand the definition of a statement in java. I read through many pages on the internet and also other stackoverflow questions, but none gave me an accurate answer.

How many statements do we have here?

```
...
assertTrue(Arrays.equals(result.get(1), new Integer[]{2,1}));
```

I would say, this is one statement. However, we could write this also like this:

```
int x[] = new Integer[]{2,1};
assertTrue(Arrays.equals(result.get(1), x));
```

This would be 2 statements, right?

Comment: What is happening in the `...`, particularly the second one?

Comment: just initializing the variable x. Didnt expect that to be necessary to show.

Comment: "However, we could write this also like this" - well, you could write code that had the same effect, yes... but it would have a different number of statements. Yes, the second piece of code has two statements. (You could go further, introducing local variables for all of the sub-expressions, ending up with four statements...)

Comment: So can we say: there is always one statement in one line of code?

Comment: Statements are defined by any line of code in java ending in `;` so even if your code wraps multiple lines, it will only be counted as one statement if it ends with `;`

Comment: @Thatalent but a while-loop is also a statement, isnt it? And it does not end with a semicolon

Comment: Here is a really good bit of oracle documentation that should clear this up - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html

Comment: @Kingvinst, that's a fair point. Without trying to be complicated, certain aspects of Java have implicate `;`. While loops and if-else are a few examples. For loops have explicit `;` and most likely the only way to extract the exact number of statements would be to look at the Bytecode which I doubt will be any easier to understand. Statements are an execution of code which normally are denoted by `;` but there are times when code execution might or might not happen which might be the reason `;` is implicit.

Comment: A statement is just an instruction that states what the program should do. So you could even go as far as saying that the first snippet of code you posted is comprised of four statements. The assert, the `equals()`, getting the first element of `result` and the creation of the Integer array.

Comment: @Kingvinst while-loop is a type of control flow statement and it can encapsulate many expression statements. In your example they are declaration and expression statements. There are multiple types of statements each with a different definition. Just for analogy- statement is like an abstract class which says every statement is a complete unit which can be executed. Types of statements are like sub-classes which inherit from the abstract class but have their own definitions.

Answer (score 5):

The authoritative answer can be found in the [specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-14.html), 14.5. To quote (from start of chapter 14):

> The sequence of execution of a program is controlled by statements, which are executed for their effect and do not have values. Some statements contain other statements as part of their structure; such other statements are substatements of the statement.

Further on the document lists all types of statements that are supported in Java with examples. That should give you what you want. I can't quote the entire document here.

As the comments indicate it is common for a statement to end with a ";" and indeed a single ";" can be a statement in its own right (the empty statement). However, there are many other cases. Check the spec!

Comment: You are quoting the description text of chapter 14, rather than § 14.5.

Comment: Yes indeed. 14.5 is about statements, but the start of the chapter had the best "one-liner" with an overall description.